# Functional Component child component does not re-rendered after its props is updated by its Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below:

ParentComponent.js

```
let childData = 0;

function ParentComponent() {
    function handleClick() {
        childData++;
    }

    return (<>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
        <ChildComponent data={childData} />
    </>);
    }
```

ChildComponent.js

```
export default function ChildComponent(props) {
    return(<p>Child Component: {props.data}</p>);
}
```

Why after clicking `Increment button` the child component still shows the old value and does not re-render?

Comment: You need to create a new state for filterdData

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

React components only re-render when state and/or props update. Since `ContainerComponent` has no state and the `graphData` prop doesn't change then `ContainerComponent` never rerenders, nor do its children.

## Solution

Add state to `ContainerComponent`. When the `filtedData` state is updated then `ContainerComponent` will rerender, along with the children.

```
function ContainerComponent(props) {
  const { graphData } = props;
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = React.useState([...graphData]);
  function handleClick() {
    setFilteredData((data) => data.filter((x) => x > 0));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Filter</button>
      <GraphComponent data={graphData} />
      <TableComponent data={filteredData} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit functional-component-not-re-rendered-after-it-props-is-updated]

## Answer for your edited question

```
let childData = 0;

function ContainerComponent() {
    function handleClick() {
        childData++;
    }

    return (<>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
        <ChildComponent data={childData} />
    </>);
}
```

`childData` won't work either since now the object reference never changes, you just mutate the same reference each time. You would need to store `childData` in component state, and update it to get the component to rerender.

Comment: Too fast for me :)

Comment: the `data=filteredData` is also a prop for Table Component. And the filteredData is changed. So I expect the Table Component should re-render?

Comment: you are here using props to initialize a state, an antipattern afaik.

Comment: @Drew thanks for the answer, I was updating and simplifying my question while you were answering.

Comment: @buzatto An anti-pattern, yes, if you are simply storing it in state, but a common use-case is storing a copy of array data that you can apply filters against, or reset back to the original data from the passed prop value.

Comment: Or if I switch it to class components instead of functional component, would that be a better idea/pattern?

Comment: @A-Sharabiani To answer your other question, when you `filter = /* some new array */` this would be considered a mutation, same with `childData++`. React doesn't see the mutation since it uses shallow equality ***after*** a render is triggered. Mutations won't trigger the render cycle. Even in a class-based component you'd have the same issue. The react component lifecycle works exactly the same for all react components.

Comment: @DrewReese  for a filtered state I often use as approach storing keys related to filtered data itself, rather than storing filtered  data for unnecessary duplication of information.

Comment: @buzatto Sure, I don't disagree, but I don't feel like getting into this debate as it isn't directly related to the issue of object mutations and components rerendering or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below:

ParentComponent.js

```
let childData = 0;

function ContainerComponent() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [childData, setChildData] = useState(0);    

    function handleClick() {
        setChildData(childData++);
    }

    return (<>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
        <ChildComponent data={childData} />
    </>);
    }


ChildComponent.js

export default function TableComponent(props) {
    return(<p>Child Component: {props.data}</p>);
}
```

Comment: `childData` is declared `const`, so it is read-only'. `setChildData(childData++);`, or specifically `childData++` won't work.